# Displaying the results of a function using the onClick event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to solve this using pure JavaScript (No Jquery)

I have written a function that solves the first question on Project Euler. I would like to make a button that retrieves whichever value is placed in the input field, runs the function, and then displays the result in a separate div after being clicked.

```js
function problem1() {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sum; i++){

    if((i % 3 === 0) || (i % 5 === 0)){
        sum += i;
    };
}
```

```html
<div class = "problem1">
      <h4>Problem 1: Multiples of 3 and 5</h4>
      <p>If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.</p>
      <p>Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below <b>1000.</b></p>

      <input id = "input" type = "text" value ="1000"></input>
      <button onclick = "getElementById('input').innerHTML=showResult()">Solve</button>
      <div id = "result"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle to show what I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/wh9uj2j6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function problem1() {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sum; i++){ //This loop will never run since sum == 0

    if((i % 3 === 0) || (i % 5 === 0)){
        sum += i;
    };
    //nothing is returned.
}
```

Other problems: `showResult()` isn't a function, `getElementById('input').innerHTML` should be `getElementById('input').value`.

I think what you wanted to do is:

```js
function problem1(num) {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if((i % 3 === 0) || (i % 5 === 0))
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```html
<div class = "problem1">
      <h4>Problem 1: Multiples of 3 and 5</h4>
      <p>If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.</p>
      <p>Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below <b>1000.</b></p>

      <input id = "input" type = "text" value ="1000"></input>
      <button onclick = "getElementById('input').value=problem1(getElementById('input').value)">Solve</button>
      <div id = "result"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire javascript function makes no sense, try this instead:

```
function solve() {

    var sum = 0;  // result var
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value; // input for iteration
    for(var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        if((i % 3 === 0) || (i % 5 === 0)) {
           sum += i;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = sum; // print result in div
}
```